# FindOne and sort in array with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

How can i get sorted data in array by "name" in categories where '_id = 63fe948a22009cbbba53b905'?

My sample data:

```
{
    "_id": "63fe948a22009cbbba53b905",
    "options": {
        "sort": "manual"
    },
    "categories": [
        {
            "priority": 0,
            "options": "manual",
            "name": "Nazwa 1",
            "_id": "63fe8cc76d50062ae1f53821"
        },
        {
            "priority": 0,
            "options": "manual",
            "name": "Inna-Nazwa",
            "_id": "63fe8cc76d50062ae1f53822"
        },
        {
            "priority": 0,
            "options": "manual",
            "name": "Nowa",
            "_id": "63fea35cbbbaf3053ad1b25f"
        },
        {
            "priority": 0,
            "options": "manual",
            "name": "Ihahaowa",
            "_id": "63fea38118acd0f4d9ad4cac"
        }
    ],
    "updatedAt": "2023-03-01T01:10:49.817Z"
}
```

Result (sort data):

```
{
    "options": {
        "sort": "manual"
    },
    "categories": [
        {
            "name": "Ihahaowa",
            "_id": "63fea38118acd0f4d9ad4cac"
        },
        {
            "name": "Inna-Nazwa",
            "_id": "63fe8cc76d50062ae1f53822"
        },
        {
            "name": "Nazwa 1",
            "_id": "63fe8cc76d50062ae1f53821"
        },
        {
            "name": "Nowa",
            "_id": "63fea35cbbbaf3053ad1b25f"
        }
    ]
}
```

Sorry, but this is my beginnings with MongoDB. I has tried but it doesn't work:

```
await NotesModel.findOne({ _id: id }, { 'options': 1, 'categories.name': 1, 'categories._id': 1, '_id': 0 }, {'categories.name': 1})
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for version 5.2 above

```
db.data.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      _id: "63fe948a22009cbbba53b905"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      result: {
        $sortArray: {
          input: "$categories",
          sortBy: {
            name: 1 //// type sort 1 | -1 => ASC | DESC
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$result"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      categories: {
        $push: {
          name: "$result.name",
          priority: "$result.priority",
          
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "result"
  },
  
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/S3P4WtU8hTi

for lower version

```
db.data.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      _id: "63fe948a22009cbbba53b905"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$categories"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "categories.name": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      categories: {
        $push: {
          name: "$categories.name",
          priority: "$categories.priority",
          
        }
      }
    }
  },
  
])
```

try it on https://mongoplayground.net/p/S3ZAXEcHdku

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Note that "$sortArray" is available since version 5.2.

I have one more question. Can I get only "name" and "priority" from "categories"? If yes, could you tell me how?

Comment: @Sumer sure, i just updated. i did modified there. i changed `$project` to `$addFields` because we need to re-group the documents.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting an array within a document is not supported in a projection, so you won't be able to use findOne for that.

You could use aggregation with 3 stages:

- $match to filter by _id
- $project to select the fields you want returned
- $addFields with [$sortArray](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sortArray/#-sortarray--aggregation-) to order the categories

Comment: Can you give me example this solution, please?